# Procfile - Migration from Heroku to AWS Fargate

Tags: heroku, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've created a project to migrate from my heroku app to AWS Fargate.

But I couldn't find a solution for multi-module. Is there a way to do it?

In hereoku, there is a file like Procfile and we can easily set the different modules there.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

```
web: java -jar web/target/myapp-1.0.0.jar
worker:  java -jar worker/target/my-worker-app-1.0.0.jar
```

Actually I wonder that how can I handle procfile on AWS ECS?